# Enable static weaving in eclipselink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, rcp

When i run my rcp application which uses jpa, i get theese warning messages:

```
[EL Info]: 2012-05-23 22:29:26.841--ServerSession(20341825)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
[EL Warning]: 2012-05-23 22:29:27.338--ServerSession(20341825)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [infoid] for the entity class [class org.company.management.entity.Employee] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
[EL Warning]: 2012-05-23 22:29:27.339--ServerSession(20341825)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [groupid] for the entity class [class org.company.management.entity.Employee] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
[EL Warning]: 2012-05-23 22:29:27.339--ServerSession(20341825)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [employeeSchedule] for the entity class [class org.company.management.entity.Employee] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
[EL Warning]: 2012-05-23 22:29:27.34--ServerSession(20341825)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [employeescheduleid] for the entity class [class org.company.management.entity.EmployeeScheduleInfo] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
[EL Warning]: 2012-05-23 22:29:27.34--ServerSession(20341825)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [scheduleid] for the entity class [class org.company.management.entity.EmployeeSchedule] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
[EL Warning]: 2012-05-23 22:29:27.34--ServerSession(20341825)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [employeeid] for the entity class [class org.company.management.entity.EmployeeSchedule] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
[EL Warning]: 2012-05-23 22:29:27.341--ServerSession(20341825)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [employee] for the entity class [class org.company.management.entity.EmployeeInfo] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
[EL Info]: 2012-05-23 22:29:27.556--ServerSession(20341825)--bundleresource://29.fwk31583837:2_Management login successful
```

And i want to enable lazy loading.

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="Management" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>org.company.management.entity.EmployeeGroup</class>
<class>org.company.management.entity.Company</class>
<class>org.company.management.entity.Employee</class>
<class>org.company.management.entity.Schedule</class>
<class>org.company.management.entity.EmployeeInfo</class>
<class>org.company.management.entity.EmployeeSchedule</class>
<class>org.company.management.entity.EmployeeScheduleInfo</class>

<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:.cafedb;create=true"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="vodbomb"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>

  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have a build script "build.xml" to make static weaving :

```
<project name="Management" basedir=".">
<target name="define.task" description="New task definition for toplink static weaving">
<taskdef name="weave" classname="org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeaveAntTask">
</taskdef>
</target>    
<target name="weaving" description="perform weaving" depends="define.task"
<weave  source="${basedir}/src/org/company/management/entity"
                target="${basedir}/src/org/company/management/entity/woven.jar"
                persistenceinfo="${basedir}/META-INF/persistence.xml">     
</weave>
</target>
</project>
```

And i face this error when i run the ant script "build.xml":

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\J\workspace\org.company.management\build.xml
define.task:
weaving:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\J\workspace\org.company.management\build.xml:13: Exception [EclipseLink-40007]     (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.StaticWeaveException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while weaving:     C:\Users\J\workspace\org.company.management\src\org\company\management\entity
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-40001] (Eclipse Persistence Services -     2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.StaticWeaveException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while trying to open an archive from     URL: file:/C:/Users/J/workspace/org.company.management/META-INF/persistence.xml 
Internal Exception: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Total time: 242 milliseconds
```

How to enable static weaving??? I am in a mess

Answer (score 2):

[How to apply Static Weaving Ant Task with Eclipse-Link JPA in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431819/how-to-apply-static-weaving-ant-task-with-eclipse-link-jpa-in-netbeans)

Combine question and an answer and you will get working example.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is the source should be a jar, not a directory. Try giving it a jar of the compiled classes.

See,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving

Answer (score 0):

Turn it on in Eclipse using the **[DALI SETTINGS](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/whats_new002.htm)**. Note that I had to turn on Projects->Build Automatically setting otherwise it rebuilt the files constantly!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the static weaving declaration in your persistance.xml:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
    ...
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the property in your persistence.xml

```
<property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
```

You can use an exploded directory structure instead of a jar file if you like.

I had problems when the persistenceinfo location had spaces in it so I moved my persistence.xml file to the location of the class files to be woven before I weave them.